# CrystalReportViewer not displaying crystal reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports in Visual Studio 2012. I am binding a dataset to it.

```
public class Client
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}
public class Patient
{
    [Key]
    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
ClientReport clReport = new ClientReport(); //(CrystalReport instance)
clReport.Database.Tables["ClientDataTable"].SetDataSource(clientDS.Tables[0]);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = clReport;
CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

In the above code, I have checked that the dataset does contain a datatable with records. When I try to run my ASP.NET app, the webform does not show any records.
I have also created a .xsd file with a datatable called "ClientDataTable" and in design time the crystal report is bound to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to copy the "aspnet_client" folder from "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" location to the root of my asp.net application's folder.